# How to delete WKWebview cookies

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

For now I am doing like this

```
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
```

But it is not working on iOS 8, 64-bit device.

Any other way the clean cookies of WKWebview? Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Apple released new APIs for ***iOS 9 and newer versions***, so now we can remove domain-specific cookies stored for **WKWebView** with the below code.

Swift 4/5 version:

```
let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
dataStore.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
  dataStore.removeData(
    ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(),
    for: records.filter { $0.displayName.contains("facebook") },
    completionHandler: completion
  )
}
```

Below is the Swift 3 version

```
let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
    dataStore.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { (records) in
        for record in records {
            if record.displayName.contains("facebook") {
                dataStore.removeData(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(), for: [record], completionHandler: {
                    print("Deleted: " + record.displayName);
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Objective-C version -

```
WKWebsiteDataStore *dateStore = [WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore];
[dateStore
   fetchDataRecordsOfTypes:[WKWebsiteDataStore allWebsiteDataTypes]
   completionHandler:^(NSArray<WKWebsiteDataRecord *> * __nonnull records) {
     for (WKWebsiteDataRecord *record  in records) {
       if ( [record.displayName containsString:@"facebook"]) {
         [[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore]
             removeDataOfTypes:record.dataTypes
             forDataRecords:@[record]
             completionHandler:^{
               NSLog(@"Cookies for %@ deleted successfully",record.displayName);
             }
         ];
       }
     }
   }
 ];
```

The above snippet will surely work for ***iOS 9*** and later. Unfortunately, if we use ***WKWebView*** for iOS versions before ***iOS 9***, we still have to stick to the traditional method and delete the whole cookies storage as below.

```
NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *cookiesFolderPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingString:@"/Cookies"];
NSError *errors;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:cookiesFolderPath error:&errors];
```

Comment: using this approach only returns the domain level, i.e. facebook.com , it tells me there are cookies inside it. but i cannot delete or retrieve individual items. For example a session cookie inside facebook. The old approach would flatten all cookies into a single list. Is this by design or am i missing something. No information ive been able to find. - @pankaj

Comment: Have you tried removing record of type WKWebsiteDataTypeSessionStorage?

Comment: Sadly its being used as cookie, debugging in safari shows i have two domains being stored with an amount of other items being used cookies, local storage etc. And under HTTPCookieStore you see a flat list across all domains a list of cookies. This session cookie i want is in there. But not when requesting througuh tis new DataStore. I do however see the Two domain items. so its as through i need to drill down a second level.

Comment: @PankajGaikar Is there a way to delete specific cookies from a domain?

Comment: @Crystal Sorry for delayed reply. I have not specifically done that, but I believe you can do it by searching the cookie with name.

Comment: Note that the WebKit API must be called on the main thread, unlike NSHTTPCookieStorage. If you're clearing cookies in a background thread you'll need to stick to NSHTTPCookieStorage.

Answer (score 24):

Swift 3 version of Sarat's answer:

```
let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
dataStore.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { (records) in
    for record in records {
        if record.displayName.contains("facebook") {
            dataStore.removeData(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(), for: [record], completionHandler: {
                print("Deleted: " + record.displayName);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

**Supports iOS 11.0 and above**

Following solution worked well for me:

Step 1. Remove Cookie from `HTTPCookieStorage`

Step 2. Fetch data records from `WKWebsiteDataStore` and delete them.

Step 3. Create a new `WKProcessPool`

**Create a WKWebView Extension:**

```
extension WKWebView {

    func cleanAllCookies() {
        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.removeCookies(since: Date.distantPast)
        print("All cookies deleted")

        WKWebsiteDataStore.default().fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
            records.forEach { record in
                WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: record.dataTypes, for: [record], completionHandler: {})
                print("Cookie ::: \(record) deleted")
            }
        }
    }

    func refreshCookies() {
        self.configuration.processPool = WKProcessPool()
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        webView.cleanAllCookies()
        webView.refreshCookies()
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

None of these options worked for me but I found one that did:

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    config.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistentDataStore()
} else {
     // I have no idea what to do for iOS 8 yet but this works in 9.
}

let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
```

Comment: With this storage you're using a "private mode" where localStorage and others won't be available so your JavaScript may fail, but yes, it wipes everything

Answer (score 5):

In iOS9:

```
//// Optional data
NSSet *websiteDataTypes
= [NSSet setWithArray:@[
                        WKWebsiteDataTypeDiskCache,
                        //WKWebsiteDataTypeOfflineWebApplicationCache,
                        WKWebsiteDataTypeMemoryCache,
                        //WKWebsiteDataTypeLocalStorage,
                        //WKWebsiteDataTypeCookies,
                        //WKWebsiteDataTypeSessionStorage,
                        //WKWebsiteDataTypeIndexedDBDatabases,
                        //WKWebsiteDataTypeWebSQLDatabases
                        ]];
//// All kinds of data
//NSSet *websiteDataTypes = [WKWebsiteDataStore allWebsiteDataTypes];
//// Date from
NSDate *dateFrom = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
//// Execute
[[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] removeDataOfTypes:websiteDataTypes modifiedSince:dateFrom completionHandler:^{
    // Done
    NSLog(@"remove done");
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on top of all the existing answers, if you are trying to clear cookies and data records for a specific WKWebView instance 'webView' and not the 'default' stored cookies and data records, you could use the following:

```
let dataStore = webView.configuration.websiteDataStore
let cookieStore = dataStore.httpCookieStore
cookieStore.getAllCookies {
    $0.forEach { cookie in
        cookieStore.delete(cookie)
    }
}
dataStore.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
    records.forEach { record in
        dataStore.removeData(ofTypes: record.dataTypes, for: [record]) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 and shorter version:

```
let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
dataStore.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
    dataStore.removeData(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(),
                         for: records.filter { $0.displayName.contains("facebook") },
                         completionHandler: completion)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

```
    /// old API cookies
    for cookie in HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies ?? [] {
        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
    /// URL cache
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    /// WebKit cache
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
    WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(
        ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(),
        modifiedSince: date,
        completionHandler:{})
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to clearing cookies in the shared cookie storage, i'd try clearing the cache (NSURLCache) and discard the WKWebView and create a new one with a new WKProcessPool

Comment: Well, i'm afraid but this isn't working too.. I read somewhere that I have to delete local library's from device too, i'll be trying that too.

Comment: If you use WKProcessPool trick ( from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156567/getting-all-cookies-from-wkwebview/33198799#33198799 ) to share cookies between multiple WKWebViews, you need to create a new WKProcessPool too like in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like NSHTTPCookieStorage is now being used in iOS 8.2 to correctly clear cookies, as required. I had shipped an app which would run this code prior to opening a WKWebView based login:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [storage cookies])
{
    [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Where earlier than iOS 8.2 the website would auto-login using the saved cookies, it now correctly asks the user to re-login. All this happened without me shipping an update to the app. :)

Comment: It doesn't really make sense, your code and mine one are same, Though I tried this code too. Nope, This one too not working for me.

Comment: OK no problem i will wait for your answer

Comment: For now, i am clueless, and have no idea what's happening here, still will try some workaround..

Answer (score 0):

Esqarrouth's answer is only partially right.
The correct swift version is:

```
var libraryPath : String = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.LibraryDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.path!
libraryPath += "/Cookies"
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(libraryPath)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Answer (score 0):

WKWebview storing nothing inside [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].

clearing **WKWebsiteDataStore** will be the solution for this problem.

Still for IOS8 which is using WKwebview, this method is not applicable..

Answer (score 0):

**In WKWebView having issue to write and read its taking some time , So when you fetch the cookie some time you will get updated cookie but sometime it will be old one, and you will get error on any server request. I was facing this issue in 3 Days ,**

Solution: No need to store cookies in WKWebsiteDataStore.

Getting cookies:

**Swift:**

```
extension WKWebView {
private var httpCookieStore: WKHTTPCookieStore  { return WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore }
func getCookies(for domain: String? = nil, completion: @escaping ([String : Any])->())  {
        var cookieDict = [String : AnyObject]()
        httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { cookies in
            for cookie in cookies {
                if let domain = domain {
                    if cookie.domain.contains(domain) {
                        cookieDict[cookie.name] = cookie.properties as AnyObject?
                    }
                } else {
                    cookieDict[cookie.name] = cookie.properties as AnyObject?
                }
            }
            completion(cookieDict)
        }
    }
}
```

**Objective-c :**

```
-(void )getAllCookies
{
    NSMutableString *updatedCockies= [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        WKHTTPCookieStore *cookieStore = _webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore;
        NSLog(@"cookieStore *********************: %@",cookieStore);
        [cookieStore getAllCookies:^(NSArray* cookies) {
            NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
            for(cookie in cookies){
               NSLog(@"%@",cookie)
            }
            self->updatedCookie = updatedCockies;
            NSLog(@"cookie *********************: %@", self->updatedCookie);
        }];
    }
}
```

Every time you want new cookie so you need to write below code:
 Given Sharpio

**Swift :**

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    config.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistentDataStore()
} else {
     // I have no idea what to do for iOS 8 yet but this works in 9.
}

let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
```

**Objective C--**

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *wkWebConfig = [WKWebViewConfiguration new];
    wkWebConfig.websiteDataStore = [WKWebsiteDataStore nonPersistentDataStore];


self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero
                                      configuration: wkWebConfig];
```

*******Every time you will get new cookies********

Answer (score -6):

Swift version:

```
var libraryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, false).first!
libraryPath += "/Cookies"

do {
  let result = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(libraryPath)
  print(result)
} catch {
  print("error")
}
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Comment: This always returned an error for me. I passed `true` for the last parameter in `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` and it works