# Fail to clear cookies without a WKWebView alive

Tags: ios, cookies, wkwebview

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289838/how-to-delete-wkwebview-cookies) resolve how to clear cookie for WKWebView.

But the `-[WKWebsiteDataStore removeDataOfTypes:]` API only clear cookies when there is a WKWebView alive.

This is problematic because WKWebViews can be deallocated at any time during the app's lifecycle and this API should not be dependent on that.

There is a bug reported in WebKit website : https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149078 (which has an app demo)

But no solution yet. Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use another WKProcessPool after clear cookies, and no cache any more.