# httpCookieStore is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In my application, written in Swift 4, I retrieve the cookies session from `wkwebview` with this code:

```
webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies({ (cookies) in
    for cookie in cookies {
          //cookie      
    }
})
```

By necessity I had to lower the deploy target from 11 to 10.1, but

> httpCookieStore is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer

I can not find a way compatible with version 10.1 to do the same thing.

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31803708/4905076)