# Is there any way to clear SFSafariViewController's cache?

Tags: ios, swift

Is the only way to clear the cache of `SFSafariViewController` by clearing Safari's cache in the Settings app?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation yes. SFSafariViewController is meant to be secure with very limited developer interaction. Anything more complicated or custom you'd have to use a custom WKWebView. Would be nice if SFSafariViewController were a little more flexible though.

Answer (score 0):

`SFSafariViewController.DataStore.default.clearWebsiteData()`

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 16 and above there is an option to clear SafariViewController caching
via `SFSafariViewController.DataStore.default.clearWebsiteData()`.
But yeah it's recommended to use WKWebView for more complex web based actions (as it gets hard to maintain/customise SFSafariViewController).
Also refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35709357/18340745