# Reset cookies with SFSafariViewController

Tags: oauth, ios9, sfsafariviewcontroller

How to reset/remove cookies in a SFSafariViewController ?
Nothing seems available in class documentation.
Any advice to reset the cookies ?

Comment: My answer here might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40163331/2736038 basically if you want to delete the cookies make the page you land on do that.

Answer (score 1):

`SFSafariViewConroller`'s cookies are shared with Safari.

Meaning cookies can be reset in Settings by resetting Safari's cookies.

Hope this helps,

Liam

Comment: Not very user friendly... I would prefer an "application/API" solution.. any other idea ?

Comment: Didn't realise you meant during use. Only thing I can think of, of the top of my head is injecting some javascript? https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html

Comment: I clear it up by going to Safari settings, but it would be nice if we can do it on the app.