# Xamarin iOS clear cache from WKWebView

Tags: caching, xamarin, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I am doing following to clear the cache from the `WkWebView`. I would like to know how do I confirm that the cache is cleared

```
 var request = new NSUrlRequest (webURL, NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, 0);

 NSUrlCache.SharedCache.RemoveAllCachedResponses ();
 NSUrlCache.SharedCache.MemoryCapacity = 0;
 NSUrlCache.SharedCache.DiskCapacity = 0;
```

Is there a way to print the cache when making the request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27105094/1107580) looks like you do this (c# version) for iOS 9 and it will print out which records are deleted:

```
var websiteDataTypes = new NSSet<NSString>(new []
{
    //Choose which ones you want to remove
    WKWebsiteDataType.Cookies,
    WKWebsiteDataType.DiskCache,
    WKWebsiteDataType.IndexedDBDatabases,
    WKWebsiteDataType.LocalStorage,
    WKWebsiteDataType.MemoryCache,
    WKWebsiteDataType.OfflineWebApplicationCache,
    WKWebsiteDataType.SessionStorage,
    WKWebsiteDataType.WebSQLDatabases
});

WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.FetchDataRecordsOfTypes (websiteDataTypes, (NSArray records) =>
{
    for (nuint i = 0; i < records.Count; i++) {
        var record = records.GetItem<WKWebsiteDataRecord> (i);

        WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.RemoveDataOfTypes (record.DataTypes, 
            new[] {record}, () => {Console.Write($"deleted: {record.DisplayName}");});
    }
});
```

Or for iOS 8, from [ShingoFukuyama/WKWebViewTips](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/WKWebViewTips#cookie-cache-credential-webkit-data-cannot-easily-delete) you could check the subdirectories Cookies, Caches, WebKit in the Library directory are removed.

> **iOS 8**
>
> After much trial and error, I've reached the following conclusion:
>
> Use NSURLCache and NSHTTPCookie to delete cookies and caches in the same way as you used to do on UIWebView.
>
> If you use WKProccessPool, re-initialize it.
>
> Delete Cookies, Caches, WebKit subdirectories in the Library directory.
>
> Delete all WKWebViews

Comment: Still the question is how to validate that the cache is cleared

Comment: I am having error while constructing websiteDataTypes. It says "Type Foundation.NSSet<Foundation.NSString> does not contain a definition for Add and no extension method Add of type Foundation.NSSet<Foundation.NSString> could be found