# Clear WebView cache xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, wkwebview

I need to clear cache after closing WebView
I use code from [Xamarin iOS clear cache from WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989788/xamarin-ios-clear-cache-from-wkwebview)
But it has no effect. Already understand that `records.Count equals 0`

How to make it right?

```
var websiteDataTypes = new NSSet<NSString>(new []
{
    //Choose which ones you want to remove
    WKWebsiteDataType.Cookies,
    WKWebsiteDataType.DiskCache,
    WKWebsiteDataType.IndexedDBDatabases,
    WKWebsiteDataType.LocalStorage,
    WKWebsiteDataType.MemoryCache,
    WKWebsiteDataType.OfflineWebApplicationCache,
    WKWebsiteDataType.SessionStorage,
    WKWebsiteDataType.WebSQLDatabases
});

WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.FetchDataRecordsOfTypes (websiteDataTypes, (NSArray records) =>
{
    for (nuint i = 0; i < records.Count; i++) {
        var record = records.GetItem<WKWebsiteDataRecord> (i);

        WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.RemoveDataOfTypes (record.DataTypes, 
            new[] {record}, () => {Console.Write($"deleted: {record.DisplayName}");});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem by the following code:

```
NSHttpCookieStorage CookieStorage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;

        foreach (var cookie in CookieStorage.Cookies)
            CookieStorage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: The answer is just for clear the cookie, not the webview cache.