# Delete Data and cache wkwebview swift 4

Tags: swift, caching, swift4, wkwebview

I am using a wkwebview to display a URL, I need the site data and cache to deleted or not to save cache at all. I need it to load up a fresh page each time. I have tried several methods but none work.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage() // removes border

    let myURL = URL(string: "https://myURL.com")!
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)
    webView.load(myRequest)

}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove cache in WKWebview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105094/how-to-remove-cache-in-wkwebview)

Answer (score 9):

If you don't ever want caching try setting the NSURLRequest.CachePolicy to reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData when initialising the URLRequest.

e.g.

```
let request = URLRequest(url: myURL, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
```